# Image loaded by $.get() doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have an image in a div in one html doucment, whic is loaded by another document using this code:

```
$.get("injections.html", function(data) {
  if ($('#header').length) {
    $("#header").replaceWith(data.getElementById("header"))
  }
});
```

It loads text just fine but when it loads images, they show up in the page inspection but not the page itself. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Looks like `data` will be a string, and strings don't support a `.getElementById()` API (because it doesn't really make sense). You could drop the string into a hidden `<div>` or something that's actually part of the DOM, and then go find the `<img>` by id.

Comment: Seems weird to me, because it shows up in the html just fine. I'm new to Jquery, could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @Pointy can wrap string in `$()` and manipulate without needing it to be in DOM also

Comment: @charlietfl yes that'd be possible too (probably easier :)

Comment: It still isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The *success* callback function in jQuery's *$.get* and *$.post* (as well as $.ajax) will receive a *string* as parameter.

String.getElementById is *undefined*. Since you are already using jQuery, you may try the following:

```
 $("#header").replaceWith($(data).find("#header"));
```

***EDIT***

The (first) parameter received by the callback is indeed a Javascript object (or what jQuery defines as 'PlainObject').

Comment: SHould the script be in the same directory as the html? It still isn't working.

Comment: No, that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the script? More specifically, place a breakpoint within the success callback. If it's not getting there, maybe you're not pointing towards the correct path (for "injections.html").

If you're 100% sure that this works (and HTML shows up in the inspector), then maybe it's the image's _src_ that is incorrect.

Comment: The image element shows up in the page inspector, but Firefox says it can't load it. Another copy of exactly the same image that wasn't injected does show.

Comment: Could you show some of your HTML? Both pre-injection and post-injection, maybe I can give you further assistance that way.

Comment: Before : 
    <div id="header">There's supposed to be a header here.</div>

Comment: After: <div id="header">

    <img alt="The Undark Pixel" src="images/logo.png"></img>

</div>

Comment: Working example, not touched my JQuery: <img alt="The Undark Pixel" src="images/logo.png"></img>

Comment: Also, it isn't giving the image any height or width even if I tell it too, and it doesn't show the alt text.

Comment: Ok, in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1vkL9zr/) I reproduced (what I understood is) your case. If I got it right, this is just about what you're doing. If this piece of code is indeed exactly or similar to what you're doing, then there is an error that you might be ignoring: Could be that the path (_src_) of the new image you are inserting is wrong.

I'm not sure it makes any diference, but try using jQuery's _.html()_ and change the inner content of #header instead of replacing it entirely via _.replaceWith()_

Comment: I'm 100% sure is inserts right, but the image just won't load.

Comment: Well, that's really all I can think of. Just to make sure, triple -or quintuple- check that the _src_ of the image you are injecting is indeed correct. I can't really come up with anything else that's wrong

Comment: Here's what I have: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2fwEiRB3e57MU0xUHp6R1NNclk/view?usp=sharing